# extending files in extjs and overriding the base file in other files

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I have one base conatiner.js file and I am extending that file in the one container.js file and overriding it and then I am extending this overrided file again in one container.js file and overriding the extended file ... in this file I am trying to add one checkbox in a container but I am not able to get that checkbox in this container if I am extending the overidded file..but if I am extending directly the base conatiner.js file then I am able to see the checkbox.. could anyone help me to get the clear picture that what exactly the issue can be

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could show us some code..

Comment: Are you extending files or classes? And you are extending, overriding, then extending and overriding again?! This sounds like an overly complex class model, and unmaintainable code. Think of simplifying.

Answer (score 0):

do you seek something like this?

```
Ext.define('BaseContainer', {
    extend: 'Ext.Container',
    constructor: function (config) {
        var me = this;
        console.log("BaseContainer", me)
        me.callParent(arguments);

    }
});

Ext.define('FirstExtendedContainer', {
    extend: 'BaseContainer',
    constructor: function (config) {
        var me = this;
        console.log("FirstExtendedContainer", me)

        me.callParent(arguments);

    }
})

Ext.define('SecondExtendedContainer', {
    extend: 'FirstExtendedContainer',
    constructor: function (config) {
        var me = this;
        console.log("SecondExtendedContainer", me)

        me.callParent(arguments);

    }
})
```

check out the developer console. in every log entry, you can access the checkbox "me.items.items" path.

fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2p5a